# how to determine which named range the user has clicked in

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, named-ranges

I have several NAMED RANGES on different Google sheets in a single spreadsheet file.  I want my Google-apps-script code to discern which of these ranges the user has clicked in.

I know how to get the value in the active cell where the user has clicked, but I don't know how to get its address (row and column).  Even if I get the row and column, how do I know which RANGE contains that cell?

[I don't have any code that even comes close.]

I have no actual results.  What I want is something like 
     range = activeCell.parentRange    (is there a function that does this?)

Comment: ``I want my Google-apps-script code to discern which of these ranges the user has clicked in.`` Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no onClick event for Spreadsheets.  However, you can determine which named Range is being edited.  You will have to install and onEdit trigger for InstallonEdit and don't forget to put in the e.

```
function InstallibleonEdit(e) {
  sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!="Sheet162"){return;}//You will probably want to change this sheet name
  var cell={row:e.range.rowStart,column:e.range.columnStart};
  var rA=isInNamedRanges(cell);
  if(rA) {
    var html=rA.join(', ');
    var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'In these ranges');  
  }
}

function isInNamedRanges(cell) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var nrgs=ss.getNamedRanges();
  var inrgs=[];
  for(var i=0;i<nrgs.length;i++) {
    var rg=nrgs[i].getRange();
    var columnStart=rg.getColumn();
    var rowStart=rg.getRow();
    var columnEnd=columnStart + rg.getWidth() - 1;
    var rowEnd=rowStart + rg.getHeight() -1;
    var range={left:columnStart,right:columnEnd,top:rowStart,bottom:rowEnd};
    if(isCellInRange(cell,range)) {
      inrgs.push(nrgs[i].getName());
    }
  }
  return inrgs;
}

function isCellInRange(cell,range) {
  if(cell.row>=range.top && cell.row<=range.bottom && cell.column>=range.left && cell.column<=range.right) {
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

Admittedly, this is a bit long winded but should serve as an example.  Most likely you will want to removed the dialog which is what is forcing the requirement for an installed trigger.  This will also detect multiple overlapping named ranges.

This is what my sheet looked like. I change the background on the named ranges.

[image]

> You can detect the click of a check box since that action will also perform an edit.  So if you include check boxes in your ranges then you could detect users clicking on them.